# overloading a unary operator for postfix

Tags: c++

Say I have a class as such

```
class foo
{
public:
    char* operator+ ()           //unary operator - prefix before instance
    {
        return "SomeChar";
    }
};
```

Now I can use it as such

```
foo d;
std::cout << +d; //unary operator used as prefix allowed
```

Now if I wanted to use the unary operator as postfix then according to [this](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-unary-and-binary-operator-overloading-and-static-members) page

> As you can see in this case we use int as a dummy argument for
>   post-fix, when we redefine the functions for the unary increment (++)
>   and decrement (--) overloaded operators. You must remember that int
>   isn't an integer, but just a dummy argument. You can see it as a
>   signal to the compiler to create the post-fix notation of the
>   operator.

I am using + instead of ++ since both are unary operators

I could do the following

```
class foo
{
public:
    char* operator+ ()           //unary operator - prefix before instance
    {
        return "SomeChar";
    }

    //Added this for postfix unary operation
    char* operator+ (int)       //unary operator - postfix before instance
    {
       return "SomeChar";
    }
};
```

However this (postfix) does not work

```
foo d;
std::cout << (d+) ; //unary operator used as post fix ERROR (Expected an expression)
```

Any suggestions/comments on this issue ?

Comment: There is no postfix +. You cannot overload an operator that does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not allow you to *add* new operators. You can only *overload* existing ones. There is no postfix `+` operator in the language, so you cannot add it. You can overload prefix `++` and postfix `++`, because they both exist.

Answer (score 3):

`+` cannot be a postfix operator. Only `++` and `--` can.

Comment: how do i know which unary operators can be postfix operator ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators) actually has a good list of operators.

Comment: so in unary operators only ++ and -- can be postfix operators ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar check out §5.3.1/Unary operators

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a postfix + operator, this user-defined conversion:

```
char* operator+ (int)       //unary operator - postfix before instance
    {
       return "SomeChar";
    }
```

has an '`int`' parameter not by chance, try to write:

```
foo d;
std::cout << (d+3) ; // No longer an "expression required" error
```

A recommended reading is *§5.3.1/Unary operators*